# SATO CG408 Printer - Unable to print with ghostscript and pywin32

Tags: python, winapi, printing, ghostscript, pywin32

I have a basic python code using win32api to send strings to the printer like so.

```py
            printer = win32print.OpenPrinter(self._printerName)
            win32print.StartDocPrinter(
                printer, 1, ('Automated printjob', None, 'RAW'))

            
            a = win32print.StartPagePrinter(printer)
            print(a)

            a = win32print.WritePrinter(printer, data)
            print(a)

            a = win32print.WritePrinter(printer, self._cmd.fullCut)
            print(a)

            a = win32print.EndPagePrinter(printer)
            print(a)

            a = win32print.EndDocPrinter(printer)
            print(a)

            a = win32print.ClosePrinter(printer)
            print(a)

    p = Printer('sato', None)
    # p = Printer('fp2000', None)
    text = 'hello\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'.encode('utf-8')
    p.print(text)


# output for both sato and fp2000 printers
# None
# 20
# 2
# None
# None
# None
```

I've tested this code on 3 different printers with encodings utf-8 and gb18030-2000. all the printers but sato worked without any issues.

There were no error messages logged, the document appeared in the print spooler with the status changing to printing before being removed from the spooler. Same goes for printing pdf with ghostscript(works on all other printers except for sato). this is the command i used.

```
gswin64c -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dNoCancel -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dFIXEDMEDIA -sOutputFile="%printer%sato" file.pdf
```

However, printing a pdf from chrome print dialog works fine. When printing from notepad, it works occasionally but more often than not, I get the error message " page too small to print one line. try printing using smaller font".

I have also turned on logging for the sato printer, however, nothing is logged when printing from the code or from ghostscript, making me believe that the bytes are stuck somewhere between the computer and the printer.

--

After removing `-dFIXEDMEDIA` argument from the ghostscript command, ghostscript is working for the SATO printer

New command:

```
gswin64c -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dNoCancel -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dFitPage -sOutputFile="%printer%sato" file.pdf
```